# Keeping first two instances in a column of duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a long list of items where some are duplicate identification numbers in one column. The records are not duplicates all across the spreadsheet. I am looking to extract the first two rows from the first two iterations of duplicate numbers when sorted by a different value (time/date).

I've seen topics on keeping the first instance of duplicate items, but not keeping the first two instances in records. I'm looking for a formula or vba. 
Thanks

Comment: Any luck with the answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

First sort your records so that the ones you want to keep are higher up the column.

Add a column where you'll put the formula (I'm assuming the first ID number is in cell A1):

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)
```

Drag the formula to the bottom of the table and copy/paste values in place to remove the formula.

Insert a filter and you can filter on only the results of 1 and 2 to get the first two instances of the ID numbers. Copy to a fresh spreadsheet to get only those in a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subroutine that should do what you are asking, you will need to alter it to your specific data as it assumes that columns A to G hold the data you want to extract and that column A has the duplicate data, column B holds the other data you want to sort by and that there are no empty cells in the data for column A.

```
Sub SortAndExctract()

Dim wsInputWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim wsOutputWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim lInputRowNumber As Long
Dim lOutputRowNumber As Long
Dim sLastExtract As Variant 'A variant as I don't know what type of value you are looking for
Dim iColumnCounter As Integer



'Sort the worksheet, assumes that the columns are in the range A:G and that you
'Want to sort according to column A and then column B
Range("A:G").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Range("B1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Set wsInputWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set wsOutputWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
lInputRowNumber = 1
lOutputRowNumber = 1

'Until an empty cell is found check for duplicate values in column A
'Assumes that you don't have empty cells in column A within your data
'and that the duplicate values are in column A

Do While wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber, 1).Value <> Empty
    If wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber, 1).Value <> sLastExtract Then
        If wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber, 1).Value = wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber + 1, 1).Value Then
                For iColumnCounter = 1 To 6 'Assuming againg that colum G is the last column
                    'copy cells to output worksheet
                    wsOutputWorksheet.Cells(lOutputRowNumber, iColumnCounter).Value = _
                        wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber, iColumnCounter).Value
                    wsOutputWorksheet.Cells(lOutputRowNumber + 1, iColumnCounter).Value = _
                        wsInputWorksheet.Cells(lInputRowNumber + 1, iColumnCounter).Value
                Next iColumnCounter
                lInputRowNumber = lInputRowNumber + 1   'Will be incremented again later
                lOutputRowNumber = lOutputRowNumber + 2
        End If
    End If
    lInputRowNumber = lInputRowNumber + 1
Loop
End Sub
```