# Complex Multi-Conditional IF Function, return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help returning a desired figure with a complex formula. I've included a sample table with some dummy data, and have almost reached the solution which returns the correct true/false conditions but need some help printing the figure. My brain is a bit frazzled after working on this for a while...

**PROBLEM:**
I need to print the figure (6000/3000/0) based on not only calculation rule, but also return 0 if the calculated was already printed at the first instance.

**RULES**

**Method Saving (Column E)** is calculated using the methodology:

For each **university** with the same **Product** **(col B)**, and same **Agreement Year** **(col C)**, where **Total** **(col D)** returns: (6,000 if over 12,500 / 3,000 if under 12,500 / 0 if total = 0)

That is quite easy to achieve ^ -- however, the tricky part comes in when trying to **only print the method saving figure once for each entry of the same university, same product and same agreement year.**

Looking at the example table below, rows 2 & 3 both have the same university, product and agreement year. It's quite easy to produce a formula with multiple IF statements to print the calculation of either 6000/3000/0, however I **only want to print the method saving figure once, at the first instance, following that the method saving figure should be 0.**

Worth noting that in Row # 4, 6000 will be printed because even though University and Product are the same, the **Agreement Year** is different.

| Row 1 | University (col A) | Product (col B) | Agreement Year (col C) | Total (col D) | Method Saving (col E) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Manchester University | Photoshop | 2022-2023 | 20,000 | 6,000 |
| 3 | Manchester University | Photoshop | 2022-2023 | 20,000 | 0 |
| 4 | Manchester University | Photoshop | 2021-2022 | 14,000 | 6,000 |
| 5 | Manchester University | Photoshop | 2021-2022 | 14,000 | 0 |
| 6 | Oxford University | Illustrator | 2022-2023 | 8,000 | 3,000 |
| 7 | Cambridge University | Figma | 2022-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | Cambridge University | Linux | 2022-2023 | 13,000 | 6,000 |
| 9 | Bristol University | Linux | 2022-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | Coventry University | Lightroom | 2021-2022 | 20,000 | 6,000 |
| 11 | Coventry University | Lightroom | 2022-2023 | 10,000 | 3,000 |
| 12 | Coventry University | Lightroom | 2022-2023 | 10,000 | 0 |
| 13 | Coventry University | Photoshop | 2022-2023 | 4,000 | 3,000 |

I have already worked on a potential solution, which may not be the *most efficient*, but for times sake it has gotten me the furthest. I've edited the cell references to match the dummy data table.

```
=IF(OR(AND(E1<>"",B2<>B1,C2<>C1),AND(E1<>"",D2=D1,C2<>C1)),
OR(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1,D2<12500,D2<>0),3000,
OR(AND(A2<>A1,B2<>B1,D2<12500,D2<>0),3000,
OR(AND(A2=A1,B2<>B1,D2<12500,D2<>0),3000,
OR(AND(A2<>A1,B2=B1,D2<12500,D2<>0),3000,
OR(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1,D2>12500,D2<>0),6000,
OR(AND(A2<>A1,B2<>B1,D2>12500,D2<>0),6000,
OR(AND(A2=A1,B2<>B1,D2>12500,D2<>0),6000,
OR(AND(A2<>A1,B2=B1,D2>12500,D2<>0),6000,
OR(D2=0,0,0))))))))),0)
```

The above formula when entered will correctly return TRUE or 0 based on the criteria above, so it has managed to figure out the logic behind it -- I'm just now having trouble at the very end to print the respective figure (6000/3000/ or importantly 0 if either Total is 0 or the figure has already been printed)

Let me know if you have any ideas / need me to clarify anything!

Thanks!

Comment: Use a formula that calculates the result regardless of the previous duplicates. Then in another column [calculate the running count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18261231/11683) of each of the groups of duplicates, using `countifs` instead of `countif` as you have several matching columns. Then zero out those that do not have the running count equal to one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `E2` and fill down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)=1,VLOOKUP(Sheet3!$D2,{0,0;1,3000;12500,6000},2),0)
```

I used a lookup table to determine what to return, and a `COUNTIF` to only return a non-zero if the entry is the first that matches those first three columns.

[image]